# Jest Enzyme Simulate Value

Tags: javascript, enzyme, jestjs

I set up my wrapper as follows:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Uploads
      availableTemplates={[]}
      filters={{ commodity: '' }}
      actions={{
        SetFilter: (e) => { wrapper.setProps({ filters: e }); }
      }}
    />);
```

The goal of the following test is to change a radio value of 'checked' from its default false to true:

```
const input = wrapper.find('input').at(0);

    input.simulate('change', { target: input.props() });
    expect(wrapper.find('input').at(0).node.props.checked).toEqual(true);
```

Without further ado, here is my question:
When I create a test below this to check for the default value of the radio (which should be false), I'm getting true back. Presumably this is because I have altered it to true early. Is there a way to reset my input to its default state for each subsequent test?

```
expect(wrapper.find('input').at(0).node.props.checked).toEqual(false);
```

Of course, I could just move this test above the other one but I am curious as to why the above is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for above seems to be that I was testing the same instance of the wrapper each time. So when I changed a value to true that would persist through the rest of my tests. To counteract this, I created a getWrapper function which I call to get a fresh instance of the wrapper each time:

```
const getWrapper = () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Uploads
    availableTemplates={[]}
    filters={{ commodity: '' }}
    actions={{
      SetFilter: (e) => { wrapper.setProps({ filters: e }); }
    }}
  />);
  return wrapper;
};
```

In test:

```
const wrapper = getWrapper();
```